# C++ Syntax, Print Help

Tags: c++, xcode

I've written a short program

```
#include <iostream.h>

class node
{
public:
    int value;           //value stored in the node 
    node *next;          //pointer to next node 
    node *prev;          //pointer to previous node 
};

class dlist
{
public:
    node *front;       //pointer to front of list   
    node *back;        //pointer to back of list  

    dlist()
    {
        front=NULL;
        back=NULL;
    }

    void insertFront(int value);             
    void insertBack(int value);
    void removeFront();
    void removeBack();
    void insertBefore(int value,node *nodeB);
    void insertAfter(int value,node *nodeA);
    void removeBefore(node *nodeB);
    void removeAfter(node *nodeA);
    void removeNode(node *newNode);
    void printDListFront();
    void printDListBack();
};

//insert a node before nodeB
void dlist::insertBefore(int value,node *nodeB)    
{
    node *newNode;
    newNode=new node();
    newNode->prev=nodeB->prev;
    newNode->next =nodeB;
    newNode->value =value; 
    if(nodeB->prev==NULL)
    {
        this->front=newNode; 
    }
    nodeB->prev=newNode;

}

//insert a node before the front node 
void dlist::insertFront (int value)
{
    node *newNode;
    if(this->front==NULL)
    {
        newNode=new node();
        this->front=newNode;
        this->back =newNode;
        newNode->prev=NULL;
        newNode->next=NULL;
        newNode->value=value;

    }
    else
    {
        insertBefore(value,this->front );
    }
}

//insert a node after  nodeB
void dlist::insertAfter(int value,node *nodeB)
{
    node *newNode;
    newNode=new node();
    newNode->next= nodeB->next ;
    newNode->prev  =nodeB;
    newNode->value =value;

    if(nodeB->next==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\n "<< endl;
        this->back =newNode; 
    }
    nodeB->next=newNode;
    cout<<"2"<<endl;
}
//insert a node after the last node 
void dlist::insertBack (int value)
{          
    if(this->back==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"insert at back";
        insertFront(value);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"insert at back";
        insertAfter(value,this->back  );
    }
}

//remove the front node 
void dlist::removeFront ()
{
    removeNode(this->front);
}

//remove a back node 
void dlist::removeBack  ()
{
    removeNode(this->back);

}

//remove before a node 
void dlist::removeBefore(node *nodeB)
{

    if(nodeB->prev==this->front)
    {
        this->front=nodeB;
        this->front->prev=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        removeNode(nodeB->prev);
    }
}

//remove after a node 
void dlist::removeAfter(node *nodeA)
{
    if(nodeA->next==this->back)
    {
        this->back=nodeA;
        this->back->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        removeNode(nodeA->next);
    }
}

//remove a perticular node 
void dlist::removeNode(node *nodeToRemove)
{
    if(nodeToRemove==this->front)
    {
        this->front=this->front->next;
        this->front->prev=NULL;
    }
    else if (nodeToRemove==this->back)
    {
        this->back=this->back->prev;
        this->back->next=NULL ;
    }
    else
    {
        nodeToRemove->prev->next=nodeToRemove->next;
        nodeToRemove->next->prev=nodeToRemove->prev;
    }
}

//Print the list from front 
void dlist::printDListFront()
{
    node* curr2;
    curr2= this->front;
    cout<<"\n-----\n";
    cout<<"Queue\n";
    cout<<"-----\n";
    //cout<<"size:"<<getQueueSize()<<endl;
    while(curr2!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<" |"<<curr2->value<<"|";
        curr2=curr2->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}// print the Double Linked List from front


// print the Double Linked List from backwards
void dlist::printDListBack()
{
    node* curr2;
    curr2= this->back;
    cout<<"\n-----\n";
    cout<<"Queue\n";
    cout<<"-----\n";
    //cout<<"size:"<<getQueueSize()<<endl;
    while(curr2!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<" |"<<curr2->value<<"|";
        curr2=curr2->prev;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}// print the Double Linked List from back

int main()
{
    dlist *st ;
    st= new dlist();
    st->insertBack(8); 
    st->printDListFront ();
    st->insertBack(5); 
    st->printDListFront ();
    st->insertBack(6); 
    st->printDListFront ();
    st->insertFront(1) ;
    st->printDListFront ();
    st->insertFront(3) ;
    st->printDListFront ();
    st->insertBack(7); 
    st->printDListFront ();
    st->removeFront();
    st->printDListFront ();
    st->removeBack();
    st->printDListFront ();
}
```

Now, how can I get the program to display my information
AS SHOWN BELOW ... (OUTPUT)
like how can I display an empty list?

```
List created using an empty value of 0.
Empty list:
        Going forwards, I see channel 0
        Going forwards, I see channel 0
        Going forwards, I see channel 0
        Current channel is 0
        Going backwards, I see channel 0
        Going backwards, I see channel 0
        Going backwards, I see channel 0
Single node:
        Going forwards, I see channel 2
        Going forwards, I see channel 2
        Going forwards, I see channel 2
        Current channel is 2
        Going backwards, I see channel 2
        Going backwards, I see channel 2
        Going backwards, I see channel 2
Multiple nodes:
        Going forwards, I see channel 2
        Going forwards, I see channel 3
        Going forwards, I see channel 7
        Going forwards, I see channel 9
        Going forwards, I see channel 10
        Going forwards, I see channel 44
        Going forwards, I see channel 2
        Going forwards, I see channel 3
        Going forwards, I see channel 7
        Going forwards, I see channel 9
        Going forwards, I see channel 10
        Going forwards, I see channel 44
        Current channel is 44
        Going backwards, I see channel 10
        Going backwards, I see channel 9
        Going backwards, I see channel 7
        Going backwards, I see channel 3
        Going backwards, I see channel 2
        Going backwards, I see channel 44
        Going backwards, I see channel 10
        Going backwards, I see channel 9
        Going backwards, I see channel 7
        Going backwards, I see channel 3
        Going backwards, I see channel 2
        Going backwards, I see channel 44
List de-allocated.
```

Comment: Is this homework? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: It looks like you've learned about lists, and judging from the output you're going to add *iterators*. Your course material should cover them in enough detail for you to at least get started.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a doubly linked list here and from what I can understand from your question you want to display an appropriate message when you navigate or create nodes.

To do this you need to insert the appropriate `cout<<` statements in each function you are calling from the Main()

Comment: could you show be an example of how i would add a count statement ? please

Comment: I can write the program...its not difficult but I urge you to do it on your own. It will help you a lot. Please refer to this tutorial for further help....
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Comment: can you please write it i've been trying to do it now for a whole day and no luck :(

Comment: ok...here is a clue....when you are displaying your list...you either call printDListFront() or printDListBack() depending on how you want to traverse it. So if you insert the cout<< statement in those functions....you will get the desired result. Try again :)

if you dont understand something in the code....post whatever you have modified and we'll help you set it right.